# jQuery Grid Animation on mouseover

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I know we are not meant to ask plugin questions here but I am not aware of any Stack site (have searched Area51) related to just plugins so if there is one, please move this post there.

I am looking for a jQuery plugin that can do something similar to this please

http://www.dow.com/solutionism/

If someone knows of a plugin like this I would appreciate the help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you right click and inspect the element, you can simply use their script and their code for documentation.
http://www.dow.com/scriptsTS/gridaccordion/jquery.gridAccordion.js

```
                $('.grid').gridAccordion({
                    width:760,
                    height:640,
                    columns:3,
                    distance:3,
                    alignType:'centerCenter',
                    captionRight:0,
                    captionTop:0,
                    captionLeft:0,
                    slideshow:true,
                    slideshowInitDelay:2000,
                    shuffle:true
                })
```